# How to refresh table using Ajax

Tags: ajax, struts

I am working on a struts application and on a jsp page, there are two controls:
1. Dropdown
2. Table
When first time page loads, Table is displayed on the page using "logic:iterate" tag from struts library. Now, I have a requirement that when user changes the dropdown value, corresponding table rows should be filtered based on the value. I am implementing this with the Ajax call to the server and I am getting the filtered results in the list. But I am not sure how I will refresh the table. Is there a way that through Ajax I can refresh the table so that logic:iterate will again be called? Otherwise, I have to display a new table with new set of results and somehow add a mechanism to hide the old logic:iterate table.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't you just replace the whole table's html with innerHTML()?

Answer (score 0):

Support you got a table with id = "listTable"
to refresh the table with ajax, do this

```
document.getElementById("listTable").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

where it will feed the return from the server into the table.